# Flujos Streams para crear un archivo de texto con una secuencia de nums del 1 al 10 como contenido JAVA

Tags: java

Quiero crear una secuencia de números del 1 al 10 como contenido de un texto creado en Java.

He intentado esto:

```
public class CrearArchivo {

    public void escribir(){

        try{
            FileOutputStream archivo=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Migui/Desktop/archivo01.txt");

            for(int numeros=1; numeros<10; numeros++) {
                archivo.write(numeros);
            }

            archivo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No se ha realizado correctamente");
        }  
    }    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo hacer que me aparezca en el texto los números tal cual, sin que me los interprete como bytes.
Sé que puedo escribir un String con los números del 1 al 10, pero me gustaría saber como se hace para convertirlos al numero tal cual.

Answer (score 1):

Las clases `FileInputStream` y `FileOutputStream`, no se utilizan para escribir ficheros en texto plano sino para escribir ficheros con datos binarios (de ahí que salga el texto codificado).

Para texto plano, utiliza la clase `FileWriter`. Con algo así valdría:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CrearArchivo {

    public CrearArchivo () {

    }

    public void escribir(){
        File f = new File ("ficherotest.txt");
        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {
            if (!f.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Fichero creado.");
                f.createNewFile();
            }

            fw = new FileWriter(f);

            for (int numeros=1;numeros<10;numeros++) {
                fw.write(numeros + " ");
            }

            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problemas en la escritura");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```